# IE acts wierd with my javascript background changing code. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, debugging

Currently, I making a website as a personal project of mine. I've tested my javascript out and it works fine on both chrome and firefox. But when I test it in IE, only part of the code works. What's weird is that when I press f12 and open up developer tools, the code runs perfectly! Work's just as it should, with no errors what so ever.

Here's my javascript:

```
var state_Clicked = false;
var List = document.createElement("div");

function gearClick() {
    if(state_Clicked == true) {
        List.parentNode.removeChild(List);
        state_Clicked = false;
    } else {
        List.setAttribute("id", "containBox");
        List.setAttribute("class", "bgChooserBox");
        List.innerHTML = '<span class="thumback"><img onMouseDown="changeBackground(\'RD1_SlurpyNom.jpg\');" class="thumb" src="GRAPHICS/bg/RD1_SlurpyNom.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span> \
                          <span class="thumback"><img onMouseDown="changeBackground(\'FS1_SlurpyNom.jpg\');" class="thumb" src="GRAPHICS/bg/FS1_SlurpyNom.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span> \
                          <span class="thumback"><img onMouseDown="changeBackground(\'AJ1_SlurpyNom.png\');" class="thumb" src="GRAPHICS/bg/AJ1_SlurpyNom.png" width="100" height="100" /></span> \
                          <span class="thumback"><img onMouseDown="changeBackground(\'PP1_SlurpyNom.png\');" class="thumb" src="GRAPHICS/bg/PP1_SlurpyNom.png" width="100" height="100" /></span> \
                          <span class="thumback"><img onMouseDown="changeBackground(\'R1_SlurpyNom.jpg\');" class="thumb" src="GRAPHICS/bg/R1_SlurpyNom.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span> \
                          <span class="thumback"><img onMouseDown="changeBackground(\'TS1_SlurpyNom.jpg\');" class="thumb" src="GRAPHICS/bg/TS1_SlurpyNom.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></span> ';
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).appendChild(List);

        state_Clicked = true; 
    }
}

function changeBackground(name) {
    console.log('/GRAPHICS/bg/' + name);
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = 'url(/GRAPHICS/bg/' + name + ')';
    document.getElementById("logo").style.opacity = '0.4';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` is the thing most likely causing you an issue. The console is not an actual object in a DOM, its usually added there by tools like firebug, chrome developer tools, IE developer tools, etc.. newer versions of Chrome and Firefox ignore console calls when they aren't open. Or at least I think this to be the case as a lot of people are making use of console for debugging now adays and its there way of making things easier on people.

Anyway in your case with IE when you have your Dev tools open the console is an active object, thus your script isn't breaking when its opened, however when its closes the console object isn't there, and since its not there and not otherwise being ignored by the browser in such an event, the script is breaking.

IE has and likely always will be the thorn in every web developers side from now til the end of days.

if you want to debug with the console, my suggestion would be to add an if-else to the logic so you can flip back and forth with it on and off..

something like `if(console.length > 0){console.log('blah');}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `console.log` call. It requires a `console` object available, or will throw an error. That's why it works when you have the developer tools open, they provide a console.